# Help ... LL Grammar And Recursive descent parser

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, grammar, context-free-grammar, recursive-descent

I'm using ANTRL and this is my some grammar which give error to me.

```
statement
:     (name)(
    | BECOMES expression
    | LPAREN (expression (COMMA expression)*)? RPAREN
    | SHIFTLEFT name LPAREN (expression ( COMMA expression )*)? RPAREN
    )
    | OUTPUT LPAREN expression ( COMMA expression)* RPAREN
    | IF expression  THEN statement (ELSE statement)?
    | FOR name BECOMES expression TO expression DO statement
    | REPEAT statement UNTIL expression
    | WHILE expression DO statement
    | body
    | 
;
```

This is error **" Decision can match input such as "ELSE" using multiple alternatives** ".

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [backtrack option](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Grammar+options).

```
options {
    backtrack = true;
}
```

**Description**

> The new feature (a big one) is the
>   backtrack=true option for grammar,
>   rule, and block  that lets you type in
>   any old crap and ANTLR will backtrack
>   if it can't figure out what you meant.
>   No errors are reported by antlr during
>   analysis. It implicitly adds a syn
>   pred in front of every production,
>   using them only if static grammar LL*
>   analysis fails. Syn pred code is not
>   generated if the pred is not used in a
>   decision. This is essentially a rapid
>   prototyping mode. It is what I have
>   used on the java.g. Oh, it doesn't
>   memoize partial parses (i.e. rule
>   parsing results) during backtracking
>   automatically now. You must also say
>   memoize=true. Can make a HUGE
>   difference to turn on.

Comment: @Atom - Can I assume you mean *"What does backtrack do?"* ?

Comment: Yeah, sry for my bad English.

Comment: @Atom - No need to apologize, I only speak one language. :)